# CSS transition affecting box accessibility/mouse-sensitivity

Tags: css, google-chrome, z-index, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a user interface situation that i recreated [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yEXH8/1/). Please have a look.

Basically, the `box` element should always overlap all others when it is visible (when its parent `field` is in state `:hover`. This seems to work fine, visually - but try to move your mouse over the `box` element while it is still in transition. You will notice that the `:hover` on the parent element becomes obsolete, causing the `box` to close again.

However, if you wait a few moments longer before you move the mouse downwards (shortly before the transition ends or once it is done), you will see that the `box` remains open.

I did tests modifying `z-index`, even trying to make `z-index` part of the transition, but to no avail. The problem persists.

Why is this happening?

And how can i modify the CSS definitions in a way that `box` will open on `:hover` over `field` using the given CSS transition `fluid` and yet being fully accessible (frontmost) from the very first moment the transition starts?

**Notes:**

I only need this to work in Chrome exclusively.

In my live environment i use a much faster transition, but i made it much longer in this example, because it is easier to test.

I solved this issue by applying a declining `z-index` on each of the field elements, but i don't like this approach at all because it is a workaround, not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the parent `.field:hover { z-index:1; }` and change `.field > .box { position: absolute; ... }` to `.field > .box { position: relative; ... }`. This is to not remove the boxes from the flow of the page and to allow each `field` to be placed over the others when hovered

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yEXH8/3/)

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while - i'm rather busy atm. Thank You very much for your grand input! It looked promising and as for the question, given the exact code provided in the fiddle, it definitely serves as a solution. I made a mistake when putting my sample code together. There are two problems: 1) I have no fixed height for the `.field` container in my actual user interface environment. The fields can have variable heights. 2) The `.box` element should always overlap the entire `.field` object, and always start at its 0px top position (thus covering it entirely).

Comment: You can consider your answer accepted, because it does what i was looking for. But for the sake of not having to open a new question, i hope you might have some insight for me as to how to make the aforementioned changes work.

Comment: You know what's funny? I just changed `position: relative` back to `position: absolute` in my live environment, leaving the other modification you provided. And see here - it works! I can hardly believe it. I thought i had this tested. I'll check some more but it seems to be good!

Comment: Okay, it works pretty well actually. The `z-index: 1` on `:hover` seems to do the trick. Only one downside: when the box closes while the mouse is over it, the mouse remains sensitive to it, as though it were still there, while in fact it is not. Only when moving the mouse, it will become sensitive to what is actually below the mouse cursor. Is there some way to force a "redraw" in the browser? Perhaps with JS? Cause this seems to be a rendering issue.

Comment: @SquareCat Can you post a jsFiddle of the situation as it is? I'll look into it, I wouldn't think a js fix is needed

Comment: Cool. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yEXH8/4/) is a more accurate recreation of my live environment. Some of the elements are like selectboxes that open below the field. Others are multi-selectboxes that open up and cover the field. The `.lower` class simulates the behaviour for the normal selectboxes. Here's the catch: move your mouse over element #3 - you notice that it has a default cursor. Now move the mouse over element #2 and make sure you are exactly above where element #3 is. Then click the dark-gray `.box` to disappear. The cursor will remain `pointer` even though it no longer should.

Comment: @SquareCat Do you mean that once you click the cursor doesn't change to the appropriate cursor until the mouse is moved?

Comment: @SquareCat I'm afraid that's default browser behavior, because the `hover` event doesn't fire until the mouse is moved. If it really is *that* necessary you can fire the hover event on the element by attaching it to the click event with javascript, but I highly doubt that it's that valuable to you

Comment: I see your point. I'll figure this out somehow. I noticed that setting `.style.cursor` has an immediate effect. Thanks for your support!